# Object moves off screen

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
#Colors, Allways you need colors!!!!
BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
GREEN = ( 0, 255, 0)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
RED = ( 255, 0, 0)
ORANGE = ( 255, 115, 0)
YELLOW = ( 242, 255, 0)
BROWN = ( 115, 87, 39)
PURPLE = ( 298, 0, 247)
GRAY = ( 168, 168, 168)
PINK = ( 255, 0, 234)
BLUE = ( 0, 0 , 255)
pygame.init()
# Screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([700,500])
#Name of thewindow
pygame.display.set_caption("Trial to make PONG")
# Any variables!

x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0

x_coord = 10
y_coord = 250

x = 670
y = 250
other_speed = 0
other_speed2 = 0

rect_x = 50
rect_y = 50

rect_change_x = 5
rect_change_y = 5
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#Sounds,maybe needed?

#Main Loop__________

done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

             # User pressed down on a key
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # Figure out if it was an arrow key. If so
            # adjust speed.

            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_speed = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed = 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                other_speed2 = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                other_speed2 = 5

    # User let up on a key
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        # If it is an arrow key, reset vector back to zero
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_speed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                other_speed2 = 0


# Move the object according to the speed vector.
    x_coord += x_speed
    y_coord += y_speed
    x +=  x_speed
    y +=  other_speed2


    screen.fill(BLACK)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,[x_coord,y_coord,20,60])
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,YELLOW,[x,y,20,60])

    if x > 650 or x < 0:

    # Draw the rectangle
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, BLUE, [rect_x, rect_y, 50, 50])

    # Move the rectangle starting point
    rect_x += rect_change_x
    rect_y += rect_change_y

    if rect_x > 650 or rect_x < 0:
        rect_change_x = rect_change_x * -1
    if rect_y > 450 or rect_y < 0:
        rect_change_y = rect_change_y * -1





    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Ok so I have 2 paddles in this pong game called  Blue and yellow rectangle. I can move them but they move off the screen. How do I prevent that. Iv looked online but nothing seems to be working. I thought about putting rectangles around the screen to make a collision point argument where when the Blue/Yellow paddle hit it they won't move any further, but im not sure how to do that with ought ruining the code? Thank you for your help..

Comment: your formatting is a bit mucked up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check to see if it's off the edge of the screen before you change the y coordinate. See

```
if y_coord + y_speed >= 0 and y_coord + y_speed + 60 <= 500:
    y_coord += y_speed
```

Though as you can see it can get a little confusing to use numbers, which is why you should avoid hard-coding. It's better to have a `display_height`, `display_width`, and `y_speed` variable. Basically, outside of initializing variables, you should only have 0s as numbers. Also, note what happens when you leave out `+ y_speed` in the if statement.

Comment: I tried as you said but it only makes the paddle (the BLUE one) go even faster off screen than before, same thing happens if I leave + y_speed out of the if statement. Thank you for your help anyways....

Comment: Wait, then you're implementing it wrong. I plugged the code directly into Python and it worked perfectly. Did you copy and paste the code and check formatting? You just need to add the line `if y_coord + y_speed >= 0 and y_coord + y_speed + 60 <= 500:` before your already existing `y_coord += y_speed`. I feel like you added this without removing that.

Comment: ahhhh. It was my fault on that, shouldve seen it. Thank you, it worked. And I can appl this to my other yellow paddle as well?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you start using the [`Rect` class](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect), since it makes handling such cases easy. Also, your code will become cleaner and shorter.

Here's an example of using `Rect`. Note that I simply use [`clamp_ip`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clamp_ip) to ensure the player paddles can't leave the screen:

```
import pygame

BLACK = pygame.color.Color('Black')
YELLOW = pygame.color.Color('Yellow')
BLUE = pygame.color.Color('Blue')

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([700,500])
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

pygame.display.set_caption("Trial to make PONG")

blue_rect = pygame.Rect(10, 250, 20, 60)
yellow_rect = pygame.Rect(670, 250, 20, 60)
ball_rect = pygame.Rect(50, 50, 50, 50)

ball_x_speed = 5
ball_y_speed = 5

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # check all pressed keys and move the paddles
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_UP]: blue_rect.move_ip(0, -5)
    if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]: blue_rect.move_ip(0, 5)
    if pressed[pygame.K_w]: yellow_rect.move_ip(0, -5)
    if pressed[pygame.K_s]: yellow_rect.move_ip(0, 5)

    # ensure paddles stay on screen
    blue_rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)
    yellow_rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)

    # move the ball
    ball_rect.move_ip(ball_x_speed, ball_y_speed)

    # check if the ball needs to change direction
    if ball_rect.x  + ball_rect.width > screen_rect.width or ball_rect.x < 0:
        ball_x_speed = ball_x_speed * -1
    if ball_rect.y  + ball_rect.height> screen_rect.height or ball_rect.y < 0:
        ball_y_speed = ball_y_speed * -1

    # draw everything
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, BLUE, ball_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE, blue_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,YELLOW, yellow_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Hey sloth! Just have a couple questions. First, just to clarify on clamp after reading docs.. It will only adjust the paddle if it's outside the screen Rect, and will move it back to the edge it left from if it did leave? Second, shouldn't clamp be after the move? Currently, I imagine the paddle is clamped, moves up (say, past the edge) and is drawn slightly offscreen. Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) The clamp is already after the move. The lines right before the `clamp_ip` stuff.

Comment: My mistake, it is the ball that is moving after the clamp! Not the paddles

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're setting the height of the screen to be 500 pixels.  Maybe you could check if your paddles are at the limit of the screen before moving them.

```
newY = y_coord + y_speed
if newY >= 0 and newY + PADDLE_HEIGHT < SCREEN_HEIGHT:
    y_coord = newy
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesnt seem to work... When I try to move the paddle it moves slightly right and left but no more after that.. When you change the paddle hiehgt to something larger than 250 then it still moves off screen.